# How to make Nginx rule work for deep links?

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

The below nginx rule-

```
 rewrite ^/component(/.*)$ $1 last;
```

Works well for

**https://example.domain.com/component/aaa**

But If the URL has more slashes means the URL is deeper the above rule doesn't work example-

**https://example.domain.com/component/aaa/bbb** OR
**https://example.domain.com/component/aaa/bbb/CCC**

It fails. Please help!

Comment: Try adding a **+** after (/.*)

Comment: @user101 No luck still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below snippet,

```
^\/component(\/.*)$
```

I have used https://regex101.com/ online tool for test-cases mentioned by you @DineshRawat

[image: test-1]

[image]

[image: test-2]